# Override Magento_OfflinePayments info/purchaseorder.phtml

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml

I want to override the file in `magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/templates/info/purchaseorder.phtml`.
I copied this file to `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_OfflinePayments/templates/info/purchaseorder.phtml`.
But it still outputs the original file. Any suggestion?
To be complete: it's about the email of an new order where this template is used

Comment: Did you create a custom theme?

Comment: Yes, i can override other phtml files by placing these in this theme, but specific this one won't work

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you created [a custom theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) already. Your change should work. **Try to clear your Magento Cache and delete `var/view_preprocessed` folder**.

**Note:** Seem that you was trying to override the html template:
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

Comment: No I want to override the phtml template. I know that the file magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/templates/info/purchaseorder.phtml is being used and I want to override this one.

Comment: Another template can be overridden in your custom theme? For example, product template?

Comment: Did you try to clear Browser Cache?

Comment: Yes, another template is directly overriden. That's what's frustrating me :) Can you override this template?

Comment: Did you use One page checkout or Multi shipping addresses checkout?

Comment: One page checkout. Does this have influence?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53733/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-eline-opsommer).

Comment: @ElineOpsommer I'm chatting now.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom theme is **Test_CustomeTheme** then You have to copy **magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/templates/info/purchaseorder.phtml** to **app/design/frontend/Test/CustomeTheme/Magento_OfflinePayments/templates/info/purchaseorder.phtml**.

Comment: the registration of my custom theme is `frontend/Stanhe/tridis`. I followed exactly your path but it still doesn't work. I also cleared cache + deleted var/view_preprocessed (though i can't find this file in this directory)

Comment: is your theme applied?

Comment: Yes, i can override other phtml files by placing these in this theme, but specific this one won't work